# I'd like to filter a list according to whatever the user enters in the textbox. I'm using angularJS. Why isn't the code working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, html-lists

I try to make my own filter called myFilter and try to pipe the person array through myFilter. All I get as the output is "Enter name: " followed by a textbox. Even if I try to write letters like A or B or C, nothing gets displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src 
    ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <p>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="test" /></p>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in person | myFilter">
                    {{x}}
                </li>
           </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.filter('myFilter', function()
                                   {
                                       return function(x, test)
                                              {
                                                  var i, c=0;
                                               for (i=0; i<test.length; i++)
                                               {
                                                  if (x[i] == test[i])
                                                  {
                                                      c++;
                                                  }
                                               }
                                               if (c==test.length)
                                               {
                                                  return x;
                                               }
                                              }
                                  });

            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
                                 {
                                     $scope.person = ['Alex', 'Buddy', 
                                         'Bob', 'Aaron', 'Clay', 'Clayton'];
                                 });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're getting an error because `test` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, you're getting an error because `test` is undefined. This is because your not passing anything in for the value. You need to pass the value into the filter, like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in person | myFilter: test">
```

But you also need to handle it being null / undefined, because at first it won't have a value, so we also need to add:

```
if (test == null) {
  test = "";
}
```

Finally, the logic in the filter also needs to change. The value of `x` will be an array of names. The value of `test` will be a string. When you're doing `if (x[i] == test[i])` that is testing that one of the names `==` one of the letters in the string.

In my example below, what I do instead is to check that the name starts with what has been typed in, and I remove any that don't.

Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(x, test) {
    var i, c = 0;
    // Set default value:
    if (test == null) {
      test = "";
    }
    
    return x.filter(function(name) {
      return name.indexOf(test) === 0;
    });
  }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.person = ['Alex', 'Buddy',
    'Bob', 'Aaron', 'Clay', 'Clayton'
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="test" /></p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in person | myFilter: test">
        {{x}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this does work perfectly, is there a way to access the characters of the array elements of x inside the filter's function?

Comment: Yep, inside the `x.filter` function use `Array.from(name)` which will return an array of the characters from `name`